# SonarCube Vs SonarSource

Tags: sonarqube

I'm doing some research about Sonar but I am not able to understand the main difference between [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org) and [SonarSource](https://www.sonarsource.com)? And SonarQube is free or no? Because I'm not able to see the prices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SonarSource is the company and SonarQube is one of their products. Their [pricing](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/) page pretty much tells you want to want to know.

You can host a SonarQube instance via Docker for free. Find the Docker image [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube).